# graphics.setcolor - what parameter?

Tags: java-me

im using the Graphics.setColor() to set the color of an arc im drawing. what im tring to figure out is what color format do i stick into the brackets. its not RGB because i cant use letters

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in a [`Color`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/Color.htm) object.

The [documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicssetColorColorc.htm) is quite clear - didn't you check it?

---

You *can* do the following:

```
g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 0);
```

Where `g` is an object of type `Graphics`.

Comment: yes I DID but you can also pass in a numeric value I'm just trying to find out what color format the numeric values correspond too

Comment: @kevin - I only see _one_ overload, taking a color. Can you link to where it can take a number?

Comment: It was RGB. It was syntax i was looking for dude... anyway it looks like this         g.setColor(255, 255, 0); // is yellow

Comment: @kevin - a link to where you saw this would help me understand.

Comment: just figured it out myself... no link sorry

Comment: "The documentation is quite clear - didn't you check it?"  Harsh!  Question is tagged "java-me", so he's talking about this method :: http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#setColor(int)

Comment: @funkytbro - The documentation you linked to is rather clear as well.